# Connect to the database in blocks

Tags: 7, database

I want to use some query of database in blocks with Drupal Database API.
I try a lot but my code doesn't work.
It is a code that I made by Drupal Database API.

```
<?php
$now =date("YmdHis");
$con = Database::getConnection();
$con->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = db_query('SELECT quiz_open, quiz_close, nid FROM {quiz_node_properties}');
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $opentime=$row['quiz_open'];
    $time_format='YmdHis';
    $opentime_hu= unix_timestamp_to_human($opentime, $time_format);
    echo '<br />';
    $closetime=$row['quiz_close'];
    $time_format='YmdHis';
    $closetime_hu= unix_timestamp_to_human($closetime, $time_format);
    if(($opentime_hu < $now) AND ($closetime_hu > $now)){
        $nid=$row['nid'];
        $result2 = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE (nid=$nid)');
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(){
            $quiz_name=$row2['title'];
            $quiz_name2=str_replace(" ","-",$quiz_name);
        }
        echo '<a href="quiz/'.$quiz_name2.'">'.$quiz_name.'</a>';
    }
}

function unix_timestamp_to_human ($timestamp = "", $format = 'Ymd- H:i:s')
{
    if (empty($timestamp) || ! is_numeric($timestamp)) $timestamp = time();
    return ($timestamp) ? date($format, $timestamp) : date($format, $timestamp);
}

?>
```

this code should do this:

```
<?php
$now =date("YmdHis");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","I_CANT_SAY_TO_YOU","I_CANT_SAY_TO_YOU","I_CANT_SAY_TO_YOU");
$con->query("SET NAMES utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quiz_node_properties ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $opentime=$row['quiz_open'];
    $time_format='YmdHis';
    $opentime_hu= unix_timestamp_to_human($opentime, $time_format);
    echo '<br />';
    $closetime=$row['quiz_close'];
    $time_format='YmdHis';
    $closetime_hu= unix_timestamp_to_human($closetime, $time_format);
    if(($opentime_hu < $now) AND ($closetime_hu > $now)){
        $nid=$row['nid'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM node WHERE nid=$nid");
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            $quiz_name=$row2['title'];
            $quiz_name2=str_replace(" ","-",$quiz_name);
        }
        echo '<a href="quiz/'.$quiz_name2.'">'.$quiz_name.'</a>';
    }
}

function unix_timestamp_to_human ($timestamp = "", $format = 'Ymd- H:i:s')
{
    if (empty($timestamp) || ! is_numeric($timestamp)) $timestamp = time();
    return ($timestamp) ? date($format, $timestamp) : date($format, $timestamp);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but my code in the drupal database API doesn't work.What's wrong???

Comment: Create block by your custom module with these codes..can't you ?

Comment: In can be,but it's a security risks. It's better to dont use the connection. I think drupal have some special code for connecting

Comment: I didn't ask you about connection as it's not needed in Drupal, you can write query in your module. You can create block by your custom module and place where ever you need by UI..

Comment: but it make a lot of problem when you want to change your server. If we have a lot of block. we should change all of them. and if you want to make a module you cant use this form

Comment: You won't have any problem with changing server & you won't have to change the code as you get automatic connection with DB in Drupal..

Comment: Blocks are display units, and database connection is a Drupal's core functionality. I don't quite get what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: @mahdialikhasi If you're using `mysqli_connect` inside a Drupal site you're probably doing something wrong. Drupal has its own database API, which should be preferred at all times

Comment: I have 2 blocks and I want to show both of them in a page and both of them have mysql_connect.because this,when I used both of this block in a page , page change to a blank page

Comment: post changed.Now I think it's clearer that before.Can you help me?

Comment: Nominated for reopening. It still could use some love, but it's not unclear now and OP certainly shows effort to get things right.